# pymacs-load does not load python modules from paths of pymacs-load-path variable

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, pymacs

I have module named qwe.py in ~/

executing next lines:

```
(setq pymacs-load-path (list "~/"))
(pymacs-load "qwe")
```

returns a error:

```
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Pymacs loading qwe...failed")
  signal(error ("Pymacs loading qwe...failed"))
  pymacs-report-error("Pymacs loading %s...failed" "qwe")
  (cond (lisp-code (let ((result (eval lisp-code))) (message "Pymacs loading %s...done" module) result)) (noerror (message "Pymacs loading %s...failed" module) nil) (t (pymacs-report-error "Pymacs loading %s...failed" module)))
  (let ((lisp-code (pymacs-call "pymacs_load_helper" module prefix))) (cond (lisp-code (let ((result (eval lisp-code))) (message "Pymacs loading %s...done" module) result)) (noerror (message "Pymacs loading %s...failed" module) nil) (t (pymacs-report-error "Pymacs loading %s...failed" module))))
  pymacs-load("qwe")
  (progn (pymacs-load "qwe"))
  eval((progn (pymacs-load "qwe")) t)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

if to copy qwe.py in /usr/lib/python2.7/ everything is ok. What am I doing wrong?

Pymacs 0.25

Emacs 24.2

## Changed this variable in pymacs.el, and it's working, pardon :)

Comment: Yes I have (manually to "/home/sergeek/"). Anyway it doesn't matter already, I just should read [this](http://pymacs.progiciels-bpi.ca/pymacs.html#pymacs-load-path) more attentively, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should change this variable in pymacs.el